# Merge Cell Range to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I display a range from Excel in Outlook's new email window?

How do I fill the To: and CC: with email addresses from specific cells within the Excel file?

I have the code below which is for object creation. (office 13)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim objEmail As Object
    Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objEmail
        .to = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Body = ""
        .Display        
    End With

    Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to fill the To section with the contents of a single cell, and the CC section with the contents of a single cell? Or are you trying to generate several New emails from a range of cells with To and CC values?

Comment: Trying to fill the TO from one cell and the CC from another cell. (User selects a business and the workbook pulls relevant info + email contacts and formats the text which i would like exported to outlook)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the cell after the TO: and it will get the value in it. Let say your email address is in B1, the code would look like this:

```
.To = Cells(1, 2).Value
```

To add a range, you need to convert it to a string before. You need to add this part before your email part:

```
Dim myCell As Range, myString As String
    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A2") 'Change range to suit your needs
        myString = myString & "," & myCell.Value
    Next myCell
'Remove extra comma
myString = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
```

With this piece of code, you'll convert your range to a string with comma between each cells. You can change "," with vbLf to get the next cell on a different line instead of a comma.

Here is an example of code with the range as a string:

```
.Body = "Hi " & Cells(1, 3).Value & "," & vbLf & vbLf _
      & "Here is the main text of my email" & vbLf & myString & vbLf & vbLf_
      & Application.UserName & vbLf & vbLf
```

In this example, it use the value in C1 as the name of the person you're writing to, your predefined text and the name of the user at the end.

Comment: Thank you the code works! Can you please advise how to include a cell range in the body of the email?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple email addresses in a range, for example in "A1:A3", you can create a list and set the .To property equal to this list (same approach for .CC):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, sTo As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Addresses")

For Each rng In ws.Range("A1:A3")
    sTo = sTo & rng & ", "                 'creates To: list
Next
    sTo = Left(sTo, Len(sTo) - 2)          'removes last ", "

With objEmail
    .To = sTo
    .subject = ""
    .Body = ""
    .Display
End With
```

Comment: Thanks GSD, what about a cell range for an email body rather then a string in TO? I have the email body prepped in excel, would like to copy it directly to my email.